# Upgrading to AppEngine Flexible Beta generates a redirect (307) for dispatch rules

Tags: google-app-engine

*Updated Question:*
The new flexible beta environment generates a redirect (that too a 307) on a dispatch rule, while the old flexible env did not.

This breaks websites like mine, because the redirected domain name is different (includes version identifier, its a fully qualified one) and hence AJAX requests from my websites fail (cross domain browser restriction). This used to not be a redirect in the past. 
Google dev's can you please assist here?

```
HTTP/1.1 307 OK
Content-Length: 180
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 19:01:53 GMT
Location: https://20161118t002457-dot-...
Server: Google Frontend
Via: 1.1 google

<html>
<head><title>307 Temporary Redirect</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>307 Temporary Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean? What have you tried? Relevant app info?

Comment: Thanks Dan for your comment. It used to work before upgrading to the new flexible vms (env: flex).

Comment: Dan, I updated the question with some more info. Would love to use your help...

Comment: The dispatch routing is not dependent on the module kind, the requests should still go to the respective module. The difference is in *how* the module handles the requests. Check the request logs for the module.

Comment: Also, just in case my above comment is not OK, check the default module logs - if the dispatcher fails to direct a request towards a certain module it'll route it towards the default module.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, but I think something did change on Google's side, since if I revert back to the old flexible vm with no code or config changes, it suddenly starts working. But as soon as I switch it to the new beta vm, it does not. I will check the logs.

Comment: Dan, can you please check my updated question? thanks!

Comment: Do you see the original request in the new module logs? If so then it's not a dispatch problem, it's just how the module operates. Not enough info, you need to debug the issue.

Comment: Dan, seems like this is a known issue. See my link in the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue, phew.
See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/-0EmVFi22Vc

Not sure, where its tracked, but I am happy Google is aware of it.

Comment: It's currently tracked at the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13406).

Answer (score 4):

Clarifying the issue:

This happens when using the new parameter `env: flex` in your app.yaml instead of the now deprecated parameter `vm: true`

A quick fix for now (December/2016) is changing the domain from `appspot.com` to `appspot-preview.com`.

[According to the GCP Team](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading), they will continue to provide both domains when GAE becomes general available