# google app engine node js redirects (307) to the full version specific url

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have an app engine node js application that uses a custom domain, although this is not just an issue with the custom domain.

Whenever I try to access the application, be it with the custom naked domain, or with www, or even requesting the default instance ( http://myapp.appspot.com/ ), I always get a 307 redirection to the full version url ( like http://version-dot-myapp.appspot-preview.com/ ).

This happens even when there is only 1 version and it is the default, and all traffic is directed to it.

Previously everything was fine, but the last deployment which included the change from `vm: true` environment to the `env: flex` environment caused this (I dont know if this is related).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658295/upgrading-to-appengine-flexible-beta-generates-a-redirect-307-for-dispatch-rul

Comment: Oh... good call. Thanks @atimothee